# Toffoli Gate Matrices

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

Here are the different toffolis (or maybe one of them is toffoli and the others are very similar to toffoli gates)

[image]

My question is:

1. we know the matrix of the number 1 Toffoli:

[image]

What are the matrices for other two toffoli gates?

Comment: I would recommend to write down a map how three-qubit basis states (000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111) are changed with the gates. Then convert the resulting basis states to vector representation and put them into a matrix (as columns) in the same order as the input states in the bracket above.

Comment: An answer to a very similar question which will show you how to answer your own question :) https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/how-to-calculate-cnot-gate-for-three-qubit-1-control-2-target-states-as-a-mat/28347#28347

Comment: very helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is much easier to think about in turns of permutations.  You can see that the matrix you created simply swaps the last two elements of the statevector:  $[a_{000}, a_{001}, a_{010}, a_{011}, a_{100}, a_{101}, a_{110}, a_{111}]$ becomes  $[a_{000}, a_{001}, a_{010}, a_{011}, a_{100}, a_{101}, a_{111}, a_{110}]$

The middle gate above swaps $a_{010}$ and $a_{011}$. The right gate swaps $a_{100}$ and $a_{101}$.  The matrix is the identity matrix, but the two $1$s corresponding to these two rows are moved to the opposite corners of the square they are corners of.

And yes, the two gates, together, make an odd parity check.

Comment: From the three examples you have, you should be able to understand the pattern of which two states swap on a CNOT. I really think you should figure this out for yourself, to show you understood my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
                             -----UPDATED------
```

Thanks to @Rajiv Krishnakumar, I solved the problem by [this link](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/how-to-calculate-cnot-gate-for-three-qubit-1-control-2-target-states-as-a-mat/28347#28347)
Here are my toffolis:
[image]

[image]
The other two toffoli was already found yesterday:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always find enlightening the block-matrix display approach, so that these three Toffoli operators can be viewed as

$$\begin{bmatrix}I& & & \\ &I& & \\ & &I& \\ & & &X\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}I& & & \\ &X& & \\ & &I& \\ & & &I\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}I& & & \\ &I& & \\ & &X& \\ & & &I\end{bmatrix}$$

where $I$ is the $2$x$2$ identity operator, $X$ is the NOT operator, and the white spaces are all zeroes for tidyness.